# How can I select every other element that does not have a specific class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a list of `<div>`s. Each `<div>` has class `zebra`. Until now I've used the following to stripe the list:

```
.zebra:nth-child(2n) { /* colors */ }
```

Now I'm implementing a filtering feature, such that some of these `<div>`s will have a class `hidden`. I tried updating my css to

```
.zebra:not(.hidden):nth-child(2n) { /* colors */ }
```

But that had no effect. What am I missing? How can I combine these selectors so that only the showing `.zebra` `<div>`s are considered in the `:nth-child(2n)`?

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NYvcv/) of what I'm describing.

**UPDATE**:

- there is an unknown number of `.hidden` elements, and an unknown total number of elements. (the list is data-driven, not static).

I'd really rather not do any of:

1. run a javascript every time a filter control is touched, just to re-color the showing list items.
2. remove an element entirely when it's hiding. this makes re-adding it non-trivial (afaict).

Comment: You can't do that. That's not how the `:not()` and `:nth-child()` pseudo-classes work.

Comment: You could reverse it and remove the `:not` part and declare some rules only for `.hidden` to override these rules.

Comment: On my iPhone it looks perfect. So perhaps this is something browser specific. Which browser are you using?

Comment: *Facepalm* I misread it.

Comment: @BoltClock I think I see now...after trying another solution using a reversed classing (`.showing` on most elements vs `.hidden` on few)...`:nth-child` is not what I wanted it to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing the element as [Justin suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13786084/237285), you could replace it with an element *of a different tag*. We could use `details`, for example:

```
var placemarker = document.createElement("details");
node.parentNode.replaceChild(placemarker, node);
placemarker.appendChild(node);
```

Then, instead of using `:nth-child`, use `:nth-of-type`.

```
details { display:none; }
div.zebra:nth-of-type(2n) { /* colors */ }
```

Unhiding the element can then be done with:

```
placemarker.parentNode.replaceChild(placemarker.firstChild);
```

See [this static example](http://jsfiddle.net/SbvKN/).

Comment: more robust than my implementation of the same solution

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind delving into jquery..

```
$('#yourHiddenElement').remove();
```

will remove it so that your css shades alternate.

http://jsfiddle.net/NYvcv/1/

I would suggest using this instead of applying the class 'hidden' to the element you want to hide.

Comment: you can use `node.parentNode.removeChild(node);` to the same effect without jQuery :)

Comment: I could do this, but then re-adding the element would be non-trivial

Comment: unfortunately I think this is my only hope...I'll sleep on it first though.

Comment: i can't think of anything else.. sorry mate!

Answer (score 0):

If you know there will be a limited number of `.hidden` items, you can do something like this:

```
.zebra2:nth-child(2n) {
    background: lightgrey;
}

.zebra2.hidden ~ .zebra2:nth-child(2n) {
    background: inherit;
}
.zebra2.hidden ~ .zebra2:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background: lightgrey;
}

.zebra2.hidden ~ .zebra2.hidden ~ .zebra2:nth-child(2n) {
    background: lightgrey;
}
.zebra2.hidden ~ .zebra2.hidden ~ .zebra2:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background: inherit;
}
```

And so on. This particular [example](http://jsfiddle.net/X3LNJ/) breaks if there are more than 2 hidden items.
​

Comment: And yes, I know it's ugly. :)

Comment: Interesting solution, but unfortunately the list is data-driven, so there's an arbitrary number of `.hidden` elements

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

use jQuery to change the `.hidden` element's type to, say, `<li>`. Use `:nth-of-type` instead of `:nth-child`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Nb68T/1/